# How to dim/blur everything outside given rect in iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm currently developing an iOS app that is using OCR.
Currently I'm using AVFoundation to preview the video from the camera (using Apples sample AVCam).

For a good user experience I want to lay out a rectangle in the preview layer. The image inside this rectangle will be the image parsed by the OCR engine. My problem is that I also would like to "dim" everything outside this rectangle and I'm currently out of ideas how to solve this. Does anybody know how to do this?

Edit
This is what I would like to accomplish (image taken from the app Horizon):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCxlO.png

Comment: Add a rectangle that covers the whole screen, colored, and with a low alpha value

Comment: But that would also dim the "live feed" inside the rectangle. I would like to dim everything outside the rectangle.

Comment: **this is simple one by adding one image view**

Comment: @kagmanoj Well, could you explain a little bit more? If I add one imageview that would surely dim even the feed inside the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two black images covering the top and bottom areas that you want to "dim", set the alpha of those images to a certain value, like 0.5.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. If I decide to not use a rectangle with full width, am I going to need to add two more views (left and right)? I will do like that to start with, but I thought there would be a solution to gray out everything outside a rect without the need to add multiple subviews.

Comment: @AndAs typically I will make an full screen size image as cover instead of creating it with code, but you need some basic image manipulating skills.

Comment: You're right. Given the fact that the rectangle will be a fixed size I could easily create an image with transparency. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a subview that covers the entire screen and set the background color to a semi transparent gray - your gray overlay?

And then add the image parsed by the OCR engine add a subview of this grayoverlay int the center of it

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that I expressed myself incorrectly. The "image inside the rectangle" is a live feed from the camera that should be without any overlay. I updated my question with a link to an image that shows what I would like to accomplish.